# Facebook sharing throwing 403 forbidden error in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook, .htaccess, user-agent, http-status-code-403

i am working on a site which is throwing 403 forbidden error when i share its blog post with facebook. Its working with twitter and google plus share, post is showing image and content as well.

[message i get when i try to share it on facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLJuc.png)

I have tried : `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*facebookexternalhit/1.1.*   [NC]`
in  .htaccess but still the result is same, i am using IP2Location block plugin to block access to certain countries except that no blocking is placed on site as of now.

I have also tried : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
its also showing the 403 forbidden error.

Does anyone has idea as to why facebook is getting 403 error when i share.

Thank you

Comment: Disable any “blocker” plugins _completely_, and try again. If that doesn’t help, then you’ll need to go and start checking relevant log files to find out what is actually going on.

Comment: site is pretty sensitive, is there any other way to debug /

Comment: Well http://elitepropertiesny.com/ is giving me Access Denied when visiting it in my browser already, so that you have currently _no_ restrictions configured sounds rather ... wrong. As I said, you’ll have to go check log files to try and find out why this request was blocked. Maybe trigger a re-scrape via the debug tool first, so that you have a rough idea around what time stamps to look.

Comment: I have enabled debugging and started checking logs against open graph object debugger request. whenever fb seems to access the site it did from different servers, some times from Netherland some times from China. Does fb access site through different server every time it tries to access it ?.

Comment: Dunno, but it probably makes sense that they shift that around for load balancing reasons; plus it might be a measure to catch people who try to serve different content to certain users with malicious intents. Don’t expect those requests to come from a specific country.

Comment: Its seems to causing the from "IP2Location Country Blocker" plugin, there is a option for that plugin to whitelist the certain url, but fb crawler has at least 300 ips after getting it from the 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler

Comment: It looks like "IP2Location Country Blocker" plugin has released a new version to resolve this issue.
https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/ip2location-country-blocker

Comment: yes they have updated the plugin, i created a support ticket yesterday, the plugin creator was quick to response...they now placed a exception for the facebook crawler....i have updated the plugin on site and tested this, the issue with 403 is not coming now. hurreyyy

Comment: Thank guys for the support though